# Attempt to index document gives error: "only value lists are allowed in serialized settings"

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing, document, elasticsearch-6

When attempting to index the following document:

```
{
"branch": "master",
"classes": [
    {
        "content_count": 2,
        "documentation": "",
        "extends": [],
        "generic": "",
        "implements": [],
        "line": 10,
        "line_count": 36,
        "modifiers": [
            "public"
        ],
        "name": "removeDuplicateFromString"
    }
],
"commit_hash": "e53249ba2381d2f20f3d4493ad70e2da0abb3b05",
"contributors": [
    {
        "id": "7676016",
        "name": "varunu28",
        "url": "https://github.com/varunu28"
    }
],
"enums": [],
"fields": [],
"filename": "removeDuplicateFromString.java",
"imports": [
    {
        "name": "java.io.BufferedReader",
        "wildcard": false
    },
    {
        "name": "java.io.InputStreamReader",
        "wildcard": false
    }
],
"interfaces": [],
"license": "",
"methods": [
    {
        "cyclomatic_complexity": 1,
        "documentation": "",
        "generic": "",
        "line": 11,
        "line_count": 9,
        "modifiers": [
            "public",
            "static"
        ],
        "name": "main",
        "params": [
            {
                "name": "args",
                "type": "String[]"
            }
        ],
        "parent": "removeDuplicateFromString",
        "type_": "void"
    },
    {
        "cyclomatic_complexity": 5,
        "documentation": "",
        "generic": "",
        "line": 29,
        "line_count": 16,
        "modifiers": [
            "public",
            "static"
        ],
        "name": "removeDuplicate",
        "params": [
            {
                "name": "s",
                "type": "String"
            }
        ],
        "parent": "removeDuplicateFromString",
        "type_": "String"
    }
],
"number_forks": 1695,
"number_stars": 4000,
"number_watchs": 394,
"package": "",
"path": "Others",
"repository": "TheAlgorithms/Java"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"settings_exception","reason":"Failed to load settings from [{\"interfaces\":[],\"imports\":[{\"name\":\"java.io.BufferedReader\",\"wildcard\":false},{\"name\":\"java.io.InputStreamReader\",\"wildcard\":false}],\"package\":\"\",\"methods\":[{\"parent\":\"removeDuplicateFromString\",\"line_count\":9,\"line\":11,\"documentation\":\"\",\"name\":\"main\",\"cyclomatic_complexity\":1,\"modifiers\":[\"public\",\"static\"],\"params\":[{\"name\":\"args\",\"type\":\"String[]\"}],\"type_\":\"void\",\"generic\":\"\"},{\"parent\":\"removeDuplicateFromString\",\"line_count\":16,\"line\":29,\"documentation\":\"\",\"name\":\"removeDuplicate\",\"cyclomatic_complexity\":5,\"modifiers\":[\"public\",\"static\"],\"params\":[{\"name\":\"s\",\"type\":\"String\"}],\"type_\":\"String\",\"generic\":\"\"}],\"number_forks\":1695,\"classes\":[{\"implements\":[],\"line_count\":36,\"extends\":[],\"line\":10,\"documentation\":\"\",\"name\":\"removeDuplicateFromString\",\"content_count\":2,\"modifiers\":[\"public\"],\"generic\":\"\"}],\"repository\":\"TheAlgorithms/Java\",\"branch\":\"master\",\"commit_hash\":\"e53249ba2381d2f20f3d4493ad70e2da0abb3b05\",\"enums\":[],\"path\":\"Others\",\"license\":\"\",\"filename\":\"removeDuplicateFromString.java\",\"number_watchs\":394,\"contributors\":[{\"name\":\"varunu28\",\"id\":\"7676016\",\"url\":\"https://github.com/varunu28\"}],\"fields\":[],\"number_stars\":4000}]"}],"type":"settings_exception","reason":"Failed to load settings from [{\"interfaces\":[],\"imports\":[{\"name\":\"java.io.BufferedReader\",\"wildcard\":false},{\"name\":\"java.io.InputStreamReader\",\"wildcard\":false}],\"package\":\"\",\"methods\":[{\"parent\":\"removeDuplicateFromString\",\"line_count\":9,\"line\":11,\"documentation\":\"\",\"name\":\"main\",\"cyclomatic_complexity\":1,\"modifiers\":[\"public\",\"static\"],\"params\":[{\"name\":\"args\",\"type\":\"String[]\"}],\"type_\":\"void\",\"generic\":\"\"},{\"parent\":\"removeDuplicateFromString\",\"line_count\":16,\"line\":29,\"documentation\":\"\",\"name\":\"removeDuplicate\",\"cyclomatic_complexity\":5,\"modifiers\":[\"public\",\"static\"],\"params\":[{\"name\":\"s\",\"type\":\"String\"}],\"type_\":\"String\",\"generic\":\"\"}],\"number_forks\":1695,\"classes\":[{\"implements\":[],\"line_count\":36,\"extends\":[],\"line\":10,\"documentation\":\"\",\"name\":\"removeDuplicateFromString\",\"content_count\":2,\"modifiers\":[\"public\"],\"generic\":\"\"}],\"repository\":\"TheAlgorithms/Java\",\"branch\":\"master\",\"commit_hash\":\"e53249ba2381d2f20f3d4493ad70e2da0abb3b05\",\"enums\":[],\"path\":\"Others\",\"license\":\"\",\"filename\":\"removeDuplicateFromString.java\",\"number_watchs\":394,\"contributors\":[{\"name\":\"varunu28\",\"id\":\"7676016\",\"url\":\"https://github.com/varunu28\"}],\"fields\":[],\"number_stars\":4000}]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"only value lists are allowed in serialized settings"}},"status":500}
```

From which I've gathered that the main issues are either described in the part saying that:

```
{"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"only value lists are allowed in serialized settings"}}
```

Or:

```
"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"settings_exception","reason":"Failed to load settings from [{\"interfaces\":[],\"imports\": ........
```

But I cannot find any information about this error or what it could be caused by. I've tried indexing both using a predefined index with mappings and to a non-existing index. Nothing seems to work.

Why can't I index this document?

Comment: What command are you running to index that document? I was able to successfully index it using `POST foo/_doc`.

Running `PUT foo` with your document as the body gave me the error you got, which makes sense since that is trying to create the mapping, but it is the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that, as Farid mentioned in the comments section, I was using the wrong command when indexing from the command line.

The correct command to run is

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' [index location] -d [data]
```

Where the key is that you use POST and not PUT which is what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this for the ones using Kibana Dev Tools.
The key is to use an **document type** after an index name when adding the document

```
POST /{index name}/{document type}
{
   request body (document) goes here.
}
```